# ca.select(...).from is not a function after minification

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, minify, squel.js

In my [Angular](https://angular.io/) app I'm using [squel.js](https://hiddentao.github.io/squel) and it works fine when used in development mode.

However when I build my app for production and try to use it, I get the following error:

> ca.select(...).from is not a function

which in the non-minified code corresponds to:

```
import * as squel from 'squel';

// ...

squel.select().from(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a [bug in squel.js](https://github.com/hiddentao/squel/issues/372) that prevents from using it after being minified.

## Solution (workaround)

1) Include sqlite as a script in `angular.json` instead of using `import` by adding it to the `scripts` array of `projects.myAppName.architect.build.options`:

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/squel/dist/squel.min.js"
]
```

Do the same for `projects.myAppName.architect.test.options` in order to fix the unit tests too.

---

2) Now the production bundle is fine, but we have to fix the typings so the ts compiler will work too.

Since we removed:

```
import * as squel from 'squel';
```

All types like `squel.Insert` will be broken.

We need to add:

```
declare const squel: Squel & {flavour: null};
```

Now all typings like `squel.Insert`, `squel.Delete`, etc... will be replaced by `Insert`, `Delete`, etc... and of course we need to import them:

```
import { Squel, Delete, Insert } from 'squel';
```

This way we use `import` only to import the type definitions and not the whole library.

## Example

https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3/commit/98f191eb59cf9c853dd8a54a845a029c7a4ddef8